# Finding out the sum of first and the last digit of any number

Tags: c

I want to write a program for finding out the sum of first and the last digit of any number entered through keyboard. For example, I entered 52264. Output must be `5+4 = 9`.

Yes, this is an assignment.

Comment: Must be homework. How else could this possibly be practical?

Comment: Ah well, then... my bad.

Comment: There is no benefit in converting the whole input string to an integer, on the opposite. Just take the first and last characters and add them (conversion from ASCII is trivial).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the last digit's easy enough to figure out, right?

```
int lastDigit = input % 10;
```

As for the first digit, I'm not sure about the most efficient way to get that. The first thought that immediately springs to my mind is:

```
int firstDigit = input;
while (firstDigit >= 10)
{
    firstDigit /= 10;
}
```

So, with 52264 for example:

```
int lastDigit = 52264 % 10; // 52264 % 10 = 4

int firstDigit = 52264;
firstDigit /= 10; // 5226
firstDigit /= 10; // 522
firstDigit /= 10; // 52
firstDigit /= 10; // 5 -- less than 10
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int n;
cin >> n;
int num1 = n % 10;
int num2 = n;
while (num2 >= 10)
     num2 /= 10;

cout << num1+num2 << endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

A different approach would be to treat the input as a string.

```
char buf[BUFSIZ];
char *p;
char bufTemp1[2];
char bufTemp2[2];
int sum;

fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);
if ((p = strchr (buf, '\n')) != NULL)
{
    *p = '\0';
}

bufTemp1[0] = buf[0];
bufTemp1[1] = '\0';

strncpy (bufTemp2, &buf[strlen(buf)-1], 1);
bufTemp2[1] = '\0';

sum = atoi (bufTemp1) + atoi (bufTemp2);
```

Comment: Much better than letting `scanf` convert from the string representation to an integer and then striving to retrieve the digits from the integer. Doing and undoing. In this case, even `atoi` is overkill.

Answer (score 1):

This should work. Since the input is an array you just need to to look at the zero element and the last one, then sum them up.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_LENGTH 256

int main () {
  char number[MAX_LENGTH];
  int first, last, sum;
  while (scanf("%s", number) == 1 ) {
    first = number[0];
    last = number[strlen(number)-1];
    sum = atoi(&first) + atoi(&last);
    printf("Sum = %d\n", sum);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Here's a sample run:

```
123456
Sum = 7
845731
Sum = 9
35846
Sum = 9
23
Sum = 5
11
Sum = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int sum=0;
    int first,last;
    int n;
    cin>>n;

    first=n %10;
    while (n!=0)
    {
        last=n/10;
    }
    sum=first+last;
    cout<<sum<<endl;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

A much more efficient way to go about doing this would be to find the number of digits beforehand, like so:

```
uint32_t digitCount = number == 0 ? 0 : (uint32_t)(log10(abs(number))) + 1;
```

From there, the process of finding the first and last digits is simplified.

Answer (score 0):

Find out total number of digits in the entered number, suppose it's *n*.

```
int temp = number;
int n = 0;

while(temp > 0)
{
   temp /= 10;
   n++;
}
```

Then

```
sum = number / (int)pow(10, n - 1)  + number % 10;
```

Comment: The last row is a waste, when it is so easy to get the leading digit in `temp`.

Answer (score 0):

here is the program:

```
/*program to find the sum of first and last digits of a given number */
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
int firstdigit,lastdigit,number,sum;

printf("Enter the number whose sum of first and last digit to be found: \n\n");
scanf("%d",&number);

if (number >=10) 
{
firstdigit = number;
while (firstdigit >= 10)
firstdigit /=10; /*firstdigit=firstdigit/10 which will neglect mantissa part;*/
lastdigit = number % 10;

sum = firstdigit + lastdigit;

printf("The sum of first=%d and last=%d digit is %d\n",firstdigit,lastdigit,sum);
}

else 
{
printf("wrong input given\n");
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("%d\n", input[0] - '0' + input[strlen(input)-1] - '0');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
b = int(raw_input())
c = str(b)
d = int(c[0])
e = int(c[-1])

print d+e
```