# Addition of all digits

Tags: c

I want to write a program to add all the digits of the entered number. For example, when I enter 54496 the output must be 5 + 4 + 4 + 9 + 6 = 28.

Comment: Have you tried anything? What do you know?

Comment: What have you coded so far? What isn't working?

Comment: possible duplicate of [finding out the sum of first and the last digit of any number ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3540440/finding-out-the-sum-of-first-and-the-last-digit-of-any-number)

Comment: @dirkgently: I only found one result here searching for `54496`.

Comment: @BoltClock: My bad, the other one uses `52264`.

Comment: hey i am just 12 yrs old i don't know too much

Comment: @shujaat: You've asked the same question before. Why don't you read the answers there? There are 7 of them (and one you've accepted).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is homework, so this is just a (quick maybe buggy) hint.

1) Initialize sum in 0;

`sum := 0`

2) take the reminder of the division by 10 of the number and add  it to sum.

```
`sum:= sum + number mod 10`
```

3) update number to the result number divided by 10.

```
 `number := number div 10`
```

4) if number > 1 goto 2

```
  `if (number greater than 1) goto 1`
```

`sum:= sum + number`