# Function Where (Last Digit of first Number)*(last digit of second number)=(Last digit of Third Number) [PYTHON]

Tags: python

according to the title its clear i want to create a function which will return True, if(Last Digit of first Number)*(last digit of second number)=(Last digit of Third Number). else False.

> I Would Like to clearly mention that i not know very well about this but still i tried several times. not all but here is my final try, if you know, please correct me if i am wrong somewhere like your disciple. Thank You.

```
def last_dig(num1,num2,num3):
  if num1[-1]*num2[-1]==num3[-1]:
    return True
  else:
    return False
last_dig(25, 21, 125)
```

> **Error was** - TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding out the sum of first and the last digit of any number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3540440/finding-out-the-sum-of-first-and-the-last-digit-of-any-number)

Comment: this is C, what if you ask me question in English and I give answer in Spanish. I don't know how to do this in python and you are giving me link of c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def last_dig(num1, num2, num3):
    last_digit_mul = (num1%10) * (num2%10)
    if last_digit_mul == (num3%10):
        return True
    else:
        return False

last_dig(25, 21, 125)
```

This will output: `True`

The `%` operator returns the **remainder** of the division of the number to it's left by the number to it's right. For example, `25%10` will return `5`  which is the **remainder** of the division `25/10`, which is also the last digit.

I believe that was the troubling part as the rest is the same as your code.

Comment: yes, you are right, that was only troubling part i am so satisfied with your answer as i was unable to understand that type of small thing... that is a bit disappointing. Thanks For Your help.